# Accessing dynamic created html checkboxes in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am dynamically creating my html checkboxes at runtime using javascript/jquery like this. It's using the Jquery bootgrid.

```
 isAssigned: function (column, row) {
                    if (row.isAssigned == "True" || row.isAssigned == "true") {
                        return "<input id='chk" + row.id + "' type='checkbox' name='chkMarks' checked='" + row.isAssigned + "' />";
                    }
                    else {
                        return "<input id='chk" + row.id + "' type='checkbox' name='chkMarks'/>";
                    }
                }
```

What I need to do is somehow get the values in my submit buttons click event in the aspx.cs code behind. I cannot runat="server" these controls because the id is not added until after the page has loaded. I need to get the id's and whether they are true or false.

I was wondering if anyone knew the best approach for me to get these values in something like this.

```
    protected void myTester_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var values = Request["chkMarks"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it!  You need to use Request.Form instead of just Request.  That should give you access to all your DOM elements.

```
var values = Request.Form["chkMarks"].ToString();
```

Here is some more information on it:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can grab something based on the name but when I foreach through the contents there are some values, they are not the id or checked value I dont think. I get two object, one has '111,0' inside and the other has '110,n', so I check the id associated and it doesnt match. I was wondering if there is another step here.

Answer (score 0):

Request.Unvalidated["chkMarks"]

can also be useful depending on what the value of this field is.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using JSON in the end using a postback so not asynchronous which is hopefully useful to someone.

```
   function BuildJSON() {
        var jsonObj = [];
        jQuery("input[name='chkMarks']").each(function () {
            item = {}
            item["id"] = this.id;
            item["isAssigned"] = this.checked;
            jsonObj.push(item);
        });
        var json = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        $('#<%= hiddenMarksID.ClientID %>').val(json);
     }
```

In the code behind I attached an event to button and picked up the JSON like so...

```
  protected void btnSubmitMarks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string json = hiddenMarksID.Value;
        List<ChkMark> chkMark = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<ChkMark>>(json);
```

Here is the POCO...

```
 public class ChkMark
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public bool isAssigned { get; set; }
}
```